# Right ideals in a ring

Tags: ring-theory

Could anyone provide me with an easy presentation of the specifics of a right ideal in a ring (inclusiveness properties, whatever)? Keep it relatively simple and water-clear, please :)
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Definition of right ideal and some properties can be obtained from [Wikipedia ](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ideal_(ring_theory)).

Comment: Keep it simple and find yourself a book, or any computer with access to internet.

Comment: Hi:  while we do sometimes accept expository posts about topics, this one does not seem to ask for anything beyond a definition which is already easily available. Do you have a specific question?

Comment: What is an "inclusiveness property"?

Comment: I mean, subset relations or the like.

Comment: Well, by reading the wiki article I do not really have the feeling to understand it, that is why i am asking. I apologize if I am too narrow-minded for your taste :)

Comment: @JavierArias This is not narrow-minded at all... quite the opposite. It's very generic. Rather than requesting an exposition, if you asked a specific question I bet you'd get an answer much more quickly.

Comment: @JavierArias Subset relations? I'm not sure what you're hoping for. Right ideals are special subsets of the ring. You may as well ask about "inclusiveness properties" of arbitrary subsets of a set. I'm not sure what one would say about that...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A right ideal of $R$ is just a submodule of the right $R$ module $R_R$ using the operation in $R$.

In symbols, a right ideal $T$ of a ring $(R,+,\cdot)$ is a subgroup of $(R,+)$ such that for all $t\in T, r\in R$, we have $t\cdot r\in T$.

A right ideal need not be a two-sided ideal. For example, in $M_2(S)$ for any nonzero ring $S$, the subset of matrices which are zero on the bottom row are a right ideal that isn't a left ideal.

The quotient $R_R/T_R$ is itself only a right module: it is a ring only if $T$ is a two-sided ideal.

Comment: There is not much more to say about right ideals in general.

Comment: Maybe this is of some interest for you all: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1610613/on-publication-regarding-right-ideals-of-a-ring-and-the-sublanguages-of-science?noredirect=1#comment3282962_1610613